# command AutoCloseWindow not valid in Section

Tags: nsis

```
Section userSoftware

MessageBox MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION  "Insert user software DVD in to drive and click  Yes to install User Software or click No to Proceed" /SD IDNO IDYES yes IDNO no
    yes:
        AutoCloseWindow true 
        SetRebootFlag false 
        Call installUserSoftware
    no: 
        ;do nothing
SectionEnd
```

Section: "userSoftware"
Error: command AutoCloseWindow not valid in Section

This is the error I am getting with AutoCloseWindow. All I am trying to do is after installing the server software if user selects to install Client software, installation of server software should disappear without asking user to hit finish button.

Code I gave I am just testing how AutoCloseWindow or SetAutoClose works, nut all I have is an error!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AutoCloseWindow` is a property like `Name` and `Installdir` and must be placed outside functions and sections. If you want to set the autoclose flag at runtime you must use the `SetAutoClose` command...

Comment: Actually what ever the script  I am working on includes **!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH**, is there any way to remove that insertmacro based on a condition. If user chooses to install user software, I do not want to show the FINISH_PAGE